# Commutation relation(s) for integrated operators

Tags: operators, commutator

Suppose I have two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$, where $\hat{A}=\hat{a_1}+\hat{a_2}+...+\hat{a_m}$, and $\hat{B}=\hat{b_1}+\hat{b_2}+...+\hat{b_n}$. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for $\hat{a_1},\hat{a_2},...\hat{a_m}$ and  $\hat{b_1},\hat{b_2},...\hat{b_n}$ to make $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0$ ?

If so, how to give a formal proof? Thanks!! (I deleted my original assumption since I found a counterexample, but I'm still wondering if there's a general relation that can be proved.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A = a_1+\cdots+a_m$ and $B = b_1+\cdots+b_n$ we see easily that:
\begin{eqnarray}
[A, B] &=& [a_1, b_1] + \cdots + [a_1, b_n]\\
&+&\\
&\vdots& \\
&+&[a_m, b_1] + \cdots + [a_m, b_n]
\end{eqnarray}
so if all $a$'s commute with all $b$'s then $[A, B] = 0$ but I don't think we can say much more. In particular, I don't see why you would need the $a$'s to commute with one another and what you mean by the $b$'s having "the same commutation relation"

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I wanted to say that all the a's should commute and all the b's should commute as well (I'll change that in my original question), sorry for the confusion. I think a's do need to commute. I tried to change my example by making $2^=⃗ 3⋅⃗ 4$, it turns out that [A,B] do not commute.

Comment: I think I have an example where a1 and b1 do not commute but $[A,B]=0$. So do we still have anything could be concluded about $a_1...a_m, b_1...b_n and [A,B]$? Thanks:)

Comment: Don't think so, because if $[A, B] = 0$ it can come from compensations between the $[a_i, b_j]$ in the expansion I wrote above, on which we cannot say anything general